# Set the height of an image after it's been downloaded in a Windows 8 App?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to set the height of an Image element dynamically in a windows 8 app. To do this, I need to know the height of the source image. Normally this can be access by calling BitmapImage.PixelHeight or BitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight, but since the image hasn't been downloaded yet it returns 0. I can set up a callback like so:

```
image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(link.Url));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("height :" + image.PixelHeight) // returns 0
instance.Source = image;
instance.Height = image.PixelHeight // what I'd like to do, but cant.
image.DownloadProgress += image_DownloadProgress;

static void image_DownloadProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressEventArgs e)
{
    BitmapImage i = (BitmapImage)sender;

    // returns the actual height I need
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("post-download height: " + i.PixelHeight); 
}
```

and I get the correct pixel height I need in that callback. The issue is that I need to pass that to the instance of the usercontrol that I'm adding that image to. Is there a way that I can either a.) pass the instance into the arguments of the callback so I can modify it there, or b.) somehow get the height asynchronously without a callback?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing to solve this kind of problem was to create a custom usercontrol to display images, which resizes itself when the image is loaded.

Here is my xaml:

```
<UserControl
    x:Name="userControl"
    x:Class="BoardsForWindows.Controls.BBPostImage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BoardsForWindows.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Image x:Name="imageViewer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </StackPanel> 
</UserControl>
```

And here is my .xaml.cs (using statements removed):

```
namespace BoardsForWindows.Controls
{
    public sealed partial class BBPostImage : UserControl
    {
        private BitmapImage bitmapImage;

        public string Source
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Source.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(string), typeof(BBPostImage), new PropertyMetadata(null, SourceChanged));

        public BBPostImage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static void SourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            BBPostImage image = d as BBPostImage;
            if (image == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            string url = (e.NewValue ?? string.Empty).ToString();
            Uri uri = null;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(url) || !Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
            {
                image.imageViewer.Width = 200;
                image.imageViewer.Height = 40;
                image.imageViewer.Source = null;
                return;
            }

            image.bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            image.bitmapImage.ImageFailed += image.bitmapImage_ImageFailed;
            image.bitmapImage.ImageOpened += image.bitmapImage_ImageOpened;
            image.bitmapImage.UriSource = uri;

            image.imageViewer.Source = null;
            image.imageViewer.Source = image.bitmapImage;
        }

        void bitmapImage_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Width = bitmapImage.PixelWidth;
            Height = bitmapImage.PixelHeight;
        }

        void bitmapImage_ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO
        }
    }
}
```